# Can NHibernate set non-public properties?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, private, protected

Is it possible to setup NHibernate to load/persist a non-public property of a class? For example I may have an Item class as follows.

```
public class Item
{
    public int ItemID {get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

With the following mapping:

```
<class name="RCL.Item" table="Items">
    <id name="ItemID" type="Int32" column="ItemID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Author" />
</class>
```

However I really don't want the consumers of my Item class to be able to change the ItemID field. Can I restrict access to the set accessor of ItemID? If so what should I set it to? Private, protected, internal, protected internal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the NHibernate tutorial:

> Properties need not be declared public
>   - NHibernate can persist a property with an internal, protected, protected
>   internal or private visibility.

Just set the ItemID to private

Comment: Humm, ok that was stupid easy. But how can NHibernate see my private accessors?

Comment: I am getting this error when property is internal. The following types may not be used as proxies:
Item: method get_ItemID should be 'public/protected virtual' or 'protected internal virtual'